# How to display static block on all pages

Tags: magento2, blocks

I wanted to display a static block with the identifer: popular_brands

I created widget:
[image]

But impossible anyway display static block before footer,  etc. I try all this option with "footer" but block is not displayed.

When I use "page top" then display correct before header. When I use "page bottom" then display correct bottom of page. But impossible set before footer etc.

[image]

Can anyone help how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

> Try this code

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="popular_brands"  before="-" >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">popular_brands</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```